# Testing docker on developement server and deploying it later and updating it with changes

Tags: docker, deployment, staging

I have my project folder "Myproject" with dockercompose.yml and context build folders of  Django_with_httpd and postgresql within it.

Inside the build context folder lies my django app code.

I am using COPY to put my code into the container.

Also i have put some intial data in my postgresql database which is lying in the docker volume created during dockercompose.

Once everything works great, I am planning to copy this entire folder and also the docker volume to the production server for staging.

Till final production:

So any change in make in the database i want to copy the volume back to prodcution server.

And also any change i make in the "Myproject" i want to copy the entire folder to production.

So is that the way things are done?

What is the best way to keep "Myproject" folder sync with that on my developement host. Should i have to use git.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be to make sure things run in a totally clean environment.  Run your application locally, against a totally empty database.  (Docker can be a good way to run the database; it is a hard way to do development.)  Your application should be able to start up and run successfully in this environment.

You may need to write migrations or database fixture code to load the initial set of data.  Since you say you need the same set of base data in all environments, it makes sense to have this checked into your source tree.

Now in Docker land you need a script that will run migrations if appropriate and then start the server.  If you’re using Django this can look something like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py migrate
exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

In your Dockerfile `COPY` that script into the image and make it be your `CMD`.  A typical Dockerfile might look like:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./
CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

Now you can just run that image in any environment with a correct database setup, and the migrations system will automatically create the base data if it’s not already there.

With this setup you will run the exact same code in development, test, and production environments.  Do not try to inject your local application code into a development-mode container; this is harder to work with than just running your code locally (maybe in a Python virtual environment) and also is fundamentally different from what you’ll use in production.

> What is the best way to keep "Myproject" folder sync with that on my developement host. Should i have to use git.

A source control system is pretty essential.  Git is very popular, but there are many other alternatives that are more ergonomic and discourage some potentially dangerous paths.

You should never be copying around the “myproject” folder.  Run `docker build` to build the image from the Dockerfile and `docker push` it to some registry.  You might look into a continuous-integration (CI) system that can automatically build and push the image whenever a change is pushed to the repository.  If this is the *only* thing you need your CI system to do then Docker Hub’s automated builds will work, but you can also generally configure things to run your tests before the actual build happens, which requires something at least a little beefier.

(The exception to this is if you have some deployment-related files like a `docker-compose.yml` file, where a source-control system is kind of the best way to save and distribute them.  In that case you might need to also check out the source repository in the production environment.  For single files like this just `scp` can work fine too.)